# Getting user input and then storing in resultSet list

Tags: java

I currently have the following code, its my Gui for a image searcher for part of my main gui, its goal from my point of view is to get user input then print out the user input and add the user input into another set of JTextFields and then use this input to search my database for matching images, the user doesn't need to select all 3 search criteria, only one. My question is that I need guidance on how to store the user input in a result set list, and then use this stored information to query my database.

So far I've tried grabbing the user input, but im unsure what i need to do next.

```
class DisplaySearch {
    // database URL                              

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    // launch the application
    public static void Search(String imageName, String DateStamp, String imageTag) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        Statement statement = null; // query statement
        ResultSet resultSet = null; // manages results

        // connect to database books and query database
        try {
            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // create Statement for querying database
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // query database                                        
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images");

            // process query results   
            System.out.println("Search Criteria");
            while (resultSet.next()) { 
                // Position the cursor 
                imageName = resultSet.getString(0); 
                DateStamp= resultSet.getString(1); 
                imageTag = resultSet.getString(2); 
                System.out.println("datas : " + imageName + " " + DateStamp + " " + imageTag ); 
            //while (resultSet.next()) {
                if (imageName != "" || imageName != null) {
                    String Name = resultSet.getString(imageName);
                    System.out.print("Image Name: " + Name);
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images where imageName='"
                            + imageName + "'");
                }

                if (DateStamp != null) {
                    String Date = resultSet.getString(DateStamp);
                    System.out.print(", Date: " + Date);
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images where DateStamp='"
                            + DateStamp + "'");
                }

                if (imageTag != "" || imageTag != null) {
                    String Tag = resultSet.getString(imageTag);
                    System.out.print(", Tag: " + Tag);
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images where imageTag='"
                            + imageTag + "'");
                }
            } // end while
        } // end try
        catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch                                                     
        finally // ensure resultSet, statement and connection are closed
        {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } // end try                                               
            catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            } // end catch                                             
        } // end finally                                             
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to store your data in a ResultSet object? I think it is not a recommended way.
You can use some variable to store your values and use them with your query to get data into a result set

Comment: How can I achieve this.

Comment: you can do something like 
if(condition1)
  sql = your query1;
else if(condition2)
  sql = your query1;
.....

then you that sql string to get results from your database

Answer (score 1):

You can add some restrictions into your code like;

```
if(imagename !="" || imageName !=null)
{
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery
    ("select imagename, DateStamp, ImageTag from images where imageName= '" + imageName + "'");
}

if(DateStamp != null
{
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery
    ("select imageName, DateStamp, imageTag from images where imageName = '"+imageName+"');
}

if(imageTag !="" || imageTag != null)
{
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery
    ("select imageName, DateStamp, imageTag from images where imageName = '"+imageName+"');
}
```

Comment: So this would help with the user only wanting to use one search option?

Comment: True, is that what you want also?

Comment: Im not sure how i can use this data to match data in my tables, and if matches print the results.

Comment: It selects all rows according to your restriction,
For example if user searches for imageName : "HolidayPhoto" 
The resultset should be like that:

imageName     DateStamp        imageTag 
HolidayPhoto  22.09.2013       someString
HolidayPhoto  23.09.2013       anotherString
HolidayPhoto  23.09.2013       someString

You can get this results in a loop..

Comment: while (resultSet.next()) {               // Position the cursor                  
 String imageName = resultSet.getString(0);
 DateStamp dateStamp= resultSet.getDateStamp(1);
 String imageTag = resultSet.getString(2);
 System.out.println("datas : " + imageName + " " + dateStamp + " " + imageTag );
}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use `String.equals(...)`, and check for `null` **before** the equality check. Plus in Java variable names start with lower case.

A simple solution would be to initialize the three variables with `*`(wildcard) and only change the value if the user entered some text, so without user input you end up with something like the following:

```
SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images WHERE imageName='*' AND DateStamp='*' AND imageTag='*'
```

plus i would suggest you to use a `PreparedStatement` where a `?` acts as a placeholder.

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT imageName, DateStamp, imageTag FROM images WHERE imageName=? AND DateStamp=? AND imageTag=?");
prepStmt.setString(1, "image-name");
prepStmt.setString(2, "date-stamp"); // maybe .setDate(...)
prepStmt.setString(3, "image-tag");
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```